# Use props instead of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know if you want to alter something within a component itself you use state, and when the emit is external then u use props to receive it. But today I stumped across this example

```
var Label = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(){
        console.log("Click");
        this.props.children = "Text After Click";
        this.setState({liked: false});
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log("Render");
        return (
            <p ref="p" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</p>
            );
    }
});
```

Used props instead of state to change the text a value of a button. I'm confused now. The link to the source is here http://myshareoftech.com/2013/12/unit-testing-react-dot-js-with-jasmine-and-karma.html

Comment: That is not good code in my opinion.  I don't think there is ever a reason to mutate received props.  It may just be for the purpose of illustrating something, not clear.

Comment: you definitely don't wanna mutate the props. There is reason why React uses this pattern, and you don't wanna mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the source but when i tried above code it throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object #`<Object>`.

It should not work because the basic property of the props is, as per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only):

> Props are Read-Only, Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must never modify its own props. All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.

Check the `fiddle` for error: https://jsfiddle.net/pjnp6yza/

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Comment: maybe the author is lost somewhere.

Comment: yes may be, what he was trying to say is change the text of the button.